# The drag and drop directive does not work as desired

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dm6eem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdrag-and-drop.directive.ts

The drag-and-drop directive implemented in the current project does not work as desired. Undefined is being printed as the name of the item, not the name of the changed item. I need advice on the cause and solution.

Comment: Why do you use `var`? And why do you expect asynchronous code to run synchronously?

Comment: I'm not used to it because I just learned how to play "Angular" and "rxjs" @KonradLinkowski

Comment: I looked through your code and I found multiple problems, but the biggest one is that you are using `innerHTML` which should never be used with Angular like this. You should edit class properties and the template will rerender. Also BehaviourSubject will be better in this case.